# How to find out what somebody's email address is without being connected to Facebook

Tags: facebook, email

If you have no way of being able to connect to Facebook but there is someone you need to contact, is there any other way of finding out what their e-mail address is?

Comment: Why can't you connect to Facebook? Do you not have an account, or are you unable to login, or is the site blocked entirely?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the URL address of that user’s profile (e.g.: `https://www.facebook.com/eminem`), your best shot could be to try and send an email to the address `username@facebook.com`, where `username` is the name coming after `facebook.com/` in the URL of the respective person’s profile (`eminem@facebook.com` in the previous example). That’s *if* the user activated this feature.

See [this help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051) for more details.

Comment: Errr...isn't facebook.com email being retired?

Comment: @AlE. Not exactly; they are retiring the option to receive those emails in Facebook Messages, forwarding them to your login email instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just ask them!     Other approaches could be considered stalking.    Or if you don't know them in real life, ask a mutual friend to introduce you through email.